# How can I convert uppercase letters to lowercase letters in ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I have the following program:

```
 .data
 cc: .byte 0x42
     .byte 0x4f
     .byte 0x4e
     .byte 0x4a
     .byte 0x4f
     .byte 0x55
     .byte 0x52
     .byte 0x00
co: .asciz "au revoir..."

    .text
    .global main
main:

@ impression de la chaine de caractere d'adresse cc
     ldr r1, LD_cc
     bl EcrChaine

@ modification de la chaine d'adresse cc
    @To be completed

@ impression de la chaine modifiee
     ldr r1, LD_co
     bl EcrChaine

fin: B exit  @ terminaison immediate du processus (plus tard on saura faire mieux)

LD_cc: .word cc
LD_ca: .word ca
LD_co: .word co
```

cc contains the string "BONJOUR" in uppercase letters. In the "to be completed" part I have to take this string and convert it in lowercase letters using a bitwise OR operation (the ORR command). My understanding is that since the string is using the ASCII table, all I have to do is add 32 to each character. The corresponding command is
`ORR R1, R1, #32`, however I'm trying to do this and when running the program the output is blank. I tried using an online emulator to see the changes in values, but I can see that only the first letter changes. Do I have to use a loop? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Yes, you have to use a loop and increment the register that stores the address of the current array element until you reach the element == 0x00 (end of string).  Also, if you have questions about your code you should show us the actual code.

Comment: Yup, `orr` with `0x20` unconditionally sets the lowercase bit, implementing `tolower()` for characters that were already alphabetic.

Comment: If you don't want a loop then you can simply repeat the code sequence modified for each next byte.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I solved my issue. I didn't use a loop because "it's next week's lesson" but here's how I did it:

First, I loaded the first 4 characters into R2 (I'm not sure if I could load more but the emulator I used can store up to 8 bytes. A character is equal to 2 bytes, thus 4 characters):

```
LDR r2, [r1]
```

and the number 32 inside R3:

```
MOV R3, 0x20
```

Then for each character I repeated this sequence of instructions:

```
ORR r2, r3, r2
LSL r3, r3, #8
```

I used LSL to multiply the value of R3 (in decimal 32, in hexadecimal 0x20) with 2 in the power of 8 (i.e. multiply with 256). As a result, with each LSL, 2 zeros were added after my number and I could use the ORR instruction on the next character.

After I finished with the first set of characters I stored them in memory and loaded the second one:

```
STR r2, [r1]
ADD r1, r1, #4
LDR r2, [r1]
```

I initialised R3 into 32 again:

```
LSR r3, r3, #24
```

and repeated ORR and LSL 3 more times. I stored that set of characters next to the first one and then went back to the start of my string and called my function that prints the string on the terminal:

```
STR r2, [r1]
SUB r1, r1, #4
bl EcrChaine
```

which worked perfectly. The resulting file however is very big in terms of number of lines and can be substantially lowered using a loop, but I didn't use one for the moment because  "we haven't been taught that in class yet".

Comment: *but the emulator I used can store up to 8 bytes*.  ARM is a 32-bit ISA.  Registers are 32-bits wide, 4 bytes.  You can only load 8 bytes if you load into multiple registers, using `ldmia` ("pop" is a special case of ldmia)  or ARMv8 `ldp` (load-pair).  Or using NEON SIMD registers like d0.  The only version of ARM with 8-byte integer registers is AArch64, and it calls them x0..x31, not r0..r15.  It's a different ISA (even though there are some chips that that can switch between ARM32 and AArch64 modes.)

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking 8 hex digits?  8 nibbles = 4 bytes.  Anyway, if you want to do 4 bytes at a time, `orr` with `#0x20202020` (you'll need it in a register).  That's more efficient than 4x `orr r2, r3, r2, ror #8` or something to rotate every byte to the bottom.  (Fun fact: AArch64 can encode `0x20202020` as an immediate for an ORR instruction, because of the repeating bit pattern.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually tried using `#0x20202020` but the university server on which I work throws an `invalid constant (20202020) after fixup` error

Comment: Right, ARM can't encode a 32-bit immediate as part of a 32-bit instruction; only AArch64 has fancy bit-pattern encodings.  You need to get it in a register with multiple instructions, like `ldr r3, =0x20202020` to let the assembler figure out how (e.g. a PC-relative load from a nearby constant in a "literal pool", or `movw` + `movk` for the low and high halves).

Comment: When working with strings in simple cases, we generally work on one byte at a time rather than attempting to work multiple bytes at a time -- this makes it easy to test for exit conditions (e.g. a given length, or null termination), and makes normal behavior easy (e.g. that strings are not always word aligned; that C string "hello"+1 == "ello").  Only in cases requiring extreme optimization (or where certain conditions are well known) would we work with multiple characters at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the word you want to convert 0x20.